# Need some guide or snippet, demo to transfer SPL token out from program's PDA account

Tags: anchor, spl-token, token

My goal is to have my own program receive any Token, store in one of PDAs of program. Then transfer they out to end user wallet.

Currently I successfully send token to program's PDA, but still not able to transfer token out.
What I have try is following this guide:
https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/anchor/transfer-tokens
but it turn out that this guide just send token from one source account to destination, have nothing to do with program's PDA.

Can anyone share some proper guide or snippet, demo?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with Anchor 0.29.0 you can use the TransferChecked Struct and transfer_checked fn that will do the invoke_signed under the hood.
And send the specific token and amount that you want.

Example:

```
    let accounts = TransferChecked {
        from: self.pda.to_account_info(),
        to: self.owner_ata.to_account_info(),
        authority: self.pda.to_account_info(),
        mint: self.mint.to_account_info()
    };

    let seeds = &[
        &b"yourseeds"[..],
    ];

    let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

    let ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        self.token_program.to_account_info(),
        accounts,
        signer_seeds
    );

    transfer_checked(ctx, amount, self.mint.decimals)
```

Make sure you are importing:

```
    use anchor_spl::token_interface::{TransferChecked, transfer_checked};
```

Comment: This looks a lot nicer than the pre-0.29 answer!

Comment: I still have problem while trying your example.  1) is 'self.pda' PDA or ATA account ?   2) is "authority" the PDA or ATA account ? 3) is it correct to set  'token_program' to 
value  'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA' ?

Comment: The above example is transfering funds out of a pda.
breeze 1-self.(name or pda account).
2- should be the same as 1. Unless you have an unchecked account just to sign things but doubt you are using, so you can use the pda.
3) No, incorrect. its self_token_program or whatever you called your type TokenInterface//0.29.0 or Token < 0.28.0

Note: ATA accounts are pdas.

Comment: I have manage to successfully fulfil my goal with your approach. But need to modify the 'from' account, not use PDA, but use ATA of PDA.
Here is my demo:  
https://beta.solpg.io/65c6342bcffcf4b13384cf58

And the 'token_program' on playground GUI input actually is TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA when on devnet.

Comment: was checking your code: your vault seeds are wrong perhaps u meant  seeds = [b"vault"].The way you have it right now its: from vault_ata to: something ata. //because you defined vault as system acc.

If you want to do it directly from pda to any ata 
your vault account would look like this:
   #[account(
        init,
        payer = maker,
        seeds = [b"vault"],
        bump,
        token::mint = maker_token,
        token::authority = auth
    )]
    pub vault: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,

TLDR: This pda already an ata. The SystemAcc is not pda.

Comment: yes, 'vault' is seed that used to derive my vault account -- a PDA account. My demo meet my requirement that support dynamic token and auth.
Does your approach fit for dynamic token ? I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, I will accept your post as answer later.

Comment: @beliveNDAOist.dev  As your latest post, we create 'ATA' in one line, but don't we stiil need PDA account to sign the CPI call? I remember that I had try to omit the PDA account, BUT the CPI call failed.

Answer (score 3):

To transfer out of a pda you'd basically have to something like:

```
let bump = *ctx.bumps.get("pda").unwrap();
let signer: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[constants::PDA_SEED, staker.as_ref(), &[bump]]];

transfer(
  CpiContext::new_with_signer(
    ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
      Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.pda.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.pda.to_account_info(),
       },
       signer,
    ),
  ctx.accounts.pda.amount, // Transfer all tokens from pda
)?;
```

This grabs the pda's seed and bump and uses it to sign the transfer out. This is written with anchor and transfer the full token amount to whatever account you put as `token_account`.

Comment: Thanks for you help.
I'm doubt `ctx.accounts.pda.amount` is correct.
Here is my demo follow your suggestion: https://beta.solpg.io/65c10271cffcf4b13384cf4a
but it raise error when invoke, error message: "Invalid account data for instruction"

Comment: Finally I make it. Key popint is change :   `ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info()` to  `ctx.accounts.vault_ata.to_account_info()`
Full code:  https://beta.solpg.io/65c4d8becffcf4b13384cf55